# Symfony event listener. How to update related entities?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Listener for university. PostUpdate function. I need to update related faculties enabled status, when updated main university status.

Here my listener in service

```
App\Entity\EventListener\UniversityListener:
    tags:
        - name: 'doctrine.orm.entity_listener'
          event: 'postUpdate'
          entity: 'App\Entity\University'
```

Here my listener inside UniversityListener

```
public function postUpdate(University $model, LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    foreach ($model->faculties as $faculty) {
        $faculty->enable = $model->enable;
        $this->em->persist($faculty);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
    return;
}
```

But on first iteration, after flush, function execute begin, from start. And faculties not updated. End here is error

```
Maximum function nesting level
```

So, how I can update related model(s)(Faculties) every time when I save main model(University)

Comment: calling flush in doctrine events can be very dangerous. I would guess that since postUpdate is a lifecycle event, that calling flush inside the event handler before the unit of work is completed (changesets are emptied) will lead to an infinte recursion. I also would say that separation of concerns would dictate you enable/disable the faculties inside the University's `setEnabled` method, instead of in a event listener.

Comment: @Jakumi  Yes, I can do this in `setEnabled`, but i can`t (or dont know how) save related model from entity setter

Comment: Will you have at any point an University as enabled but any of its Faculties as disabled? Or will they always be the same and you want to synchronize it?

Comment: Alexander: when you have persisted the faculties once, they are managed, and unless you actively changed the change tracking policy, they will be updated in database as soon as you call flush.

Comment: @MigMolRod I want synchronize it when university status updated

Comment: @Jakumi Ok, so what solution for this problem?

Comment: it really depends on your business logic. a few parts of your solution might be: 1. cascaded persists, 2. iterating through the faculties in University::setEnabled() and setting the new value on them. 3. setting the enabled value when adding a Faculty to a University. Doctrine does a lot of stuff. As soon as an entity is persisted once (done via 1. for Facultys) it will update corresponding records in db on flush. If you don't understand what I'm saying, read up on managed entities as well as cascaded persists in doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly indicates that you face infinite recursion. Since this happens at the line of `flush`, it is reasonable to accept it being the cause as a fact. Lifecycle events are not the place to flush. See: https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/6822

Call flush at `onFlush`.

Comment: I try to add this listener `public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $eventArgs)`, here I found my University entity from `$uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates()` and try to update faculties (how I show in first message) without `$this->em->flush()`. Without flush, university status updated, but facultiest not. With flush - inifinite loop again.

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko as a general idea you should do the call to ```persist``` in events before the ```onFlush``` event. That should prepare your changes and then you should be able to do the flush. However, you might have some business logic executed on flush that induces circular flush, that is, entity A's flush induces entity B's flush, but entity B's flush induces entity A's flush. You might need this trigger-like behavior in general, but if it causes this trouble, then a semaphore system might be needed. See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/lock.html#semaphorestore